# Making Azure Mobile App accept custom authentication with Node backend

Tags: node.js, azure, authentication

I'm trying to implement a custom authentication in an Azure Mobile App (not the old Mobile Service) with a Node.js backend, with actions I can't quite translate into Node. An earlier question states that custom authentication ["just works"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33827015/how-to-implement-custom-authentication-in-an-azure-mobile-app) with a .NET backend. I am having trouble getting

I have copied [Joy of code's example JWT generation](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Generating_your_own_ZUMO_auth_token_Day_8_.aspx) ([gist here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/joshtwist/4402781/raw/6b390e00f6fd680a20661dca6c3924e30506fded/zumojwt.js)). I invoke it like this (inlining the aud and userId):

```
zumoJWT(expiry,"MyAud","MyAud:1455527189540927",req.azureMobile.configuration.auth.secret);
```

My registration API returns the following JSON

```
{"user":{"userid":"MyAud:1455527189540927"},"token":"a lot of base64"}
```

Which I put into the Android MobileServiceClient with this code

```
JsonObject userob=ob.get("user").getAsJsonObject();
MobileServiceUser user=new MobileServiceUser(userob.get("userid").getAsString());
user.setAuthenticationToken(ob.get("token").getAsString());
mClient.setCurrentUser(user);
```

Which gives me the error message

> com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceException: {"name":"JsonWebTokenError","message":"invalid signature"

The next time I invoke an API. How do I make my app accept the login token?

Edit: The server-side logs say

```
2016-02-15T11:42:35  PID[180] Warning     JWT validation failed: IDX10500: Signature validation failed. Unable to resolve SecurityKeyIdentifier: 'SecurityKeyIdentifier
(
IsReadOnly = False,
Count = 1,
Clause[0] = System.IdentityModel.Tokens.NamedKeySecurityKeyIdentifierClause
)
', 
token: '{"alg":"HS256","typ":"JWT","kid":0}.{"exp":null,"iss":"urn:microsoft:windows-azure:zumo","ver":2,"aud":"MyAud","uid":"MyAud:1455534835642715"}
RawData: a lot of base64'..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to have

```
mobile.configuration.auth.validateTokens=false;
```

in app.js (or rather, not have the same variable set to true).